# Case with multiple conditions on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, case

I am trying to figure out how to make this work:

```
CASE
   WHEN a.val IS NULL AND (a.CreatedBy <> 'MDI' OR a.Type <> 'RO' OR a.Unit <> 'ER') THEN 1
   ELSE 0 
END as field_name
```

Basically I am looking for rows where `a.val` is `null`, but ignore the row if any of these columns (`a.CreatedBy` or `a.Type` or `a.Unit`) have a specific value. Even if one of these columns is true for the specific value the case should return `0`.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe the issue/error obtained. Did you try this in a query and did not get expected output? Please post sample data.

Comment: Looks like you want `AND`s in there instead of `OR`s. At the moment you are saying that only one of those 3 expressions have to be true for the whole part in parenthesis to be true. Don't you want `AND`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need AND instead of OR operators.

```
CASE    WHEN    a.val IS NULL
                AND a.CreatedBy <> 'MDI' 
                AND a.Type <> 'RO' 
                AND a.Unit <> 'ER'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
END as field_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN A.VAL IS NULL AND 
(A.CREATED_BY<>'MDI' OR A.TYPE<>'RO','AND A.UNIT<>'ER') THEN 1
ELSE 0 END 
AS COLUMNNAME
```